# Comparing numbers $a \uparrow^b c$ and $d \uparrow^e f$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there an efficient method to decide which of two numbers

$a \uparrow^b c$ and $d \uparrow^e f$ is bigger ?

The rules that hold in most of the cases are

- if b>e then $a \uparrow^b c$ is the larger number
- if b=e and c>f then $a \uparrow^b c$ is the larger number
- if b=e and c=f and a>d then $a \uparrow^b c$ is the larger number

To avoid trivial cases, let a,b,c,d,e,f > 1. We should also avoid
the cases a = c = 2 and d = f = 2, in which case the value is 4.

How can we check if we have found a counterexample for the rules
given above ?

Comment: The first two rules, as they are written, can't be generally true, because even if $b>e$ and $c>f$ , $d$ may be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Yes, therefore I would like to know when they do not hold.

Comment: See my related question on math.SE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72646/help-me-put-these-enormous-numbers-in-order-googol-googol-plex-bang-googol-s, concerning in effect iterations of such expressions.

Comment: A related slightly more general question is http://mathoverflow.net/q/119453/806